# How to sort an array of objects on the basis of the number value in the object

Tags: javascript

If I have an array of:

```
var arr = [{"apple":3}, {"pear":5}, {"orange":1}]
```

How can I sort this array based on the number value inside the objects desc order?

I want the sorted array to be：

```
[{"pear":5}, {"apple":3}, {"orange":1}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
const newArr = arr.sort((a, b) => {
return Object.values(b)[0] -  Object.values(a)[0];
});
```

Comment: Upvote for you,it would be better to put it inside a sinppet

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - @lucumt . I'm still getting used to stackoverflow's reply tools haha

Comment: `newArr === arr` - it doesn't return a new array.  It returns a reference to `arr`, which is what was sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another variable, then run the array variable with .reverse(); at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Just a reference for you,waiting for more elegant solution to it

```js
var arr = [{"apple":3}, {"pear":5}, {"orange":1}]
arr.sort((a,b)=>{
  //return b[Object.keys(b)[0]] - a[Object.keys(a)[0]]
  return Object.values(b)[0] -  Object.values(a)[0];
})

console.log(arr)
```